# Typescript will not exclude folder in the 'excludes' array of tsconfig no matter what (TS 3.7.2)

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsconfig

I've read countless threads and documentation and tried dozens of different approaches to get this to work and it simply will not ignore that testing folder no matter what.

My TS Config:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"],
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "strict": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["**/testing/*", "testing", "**/testing/**/*"]
}
```

My folder structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out excluding folders like that was quite pointless and the whole folder structure that I was seeing with "src" folder and so on was already a sign of things going wrong compared to my tsconfig which should just place the JS result of the files inside "src" straight inside "lib".

My spec files were in SRC and they were depending on assets inside the 'testing' folder. Once I excluded the spec files using:

```
  "exclude": ["src/**/*.spec.ts"]
```

I didn't need to specify the testing folder to the 'excludes' array at all. Now the result of tsc, outputs this folder/file structure without no other changes to the tsconfig:

[image]